# Gonality and Clifford dimension of curves on a K3 surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a K3 surface. Let $L$ be an ample line bundle on $X$. When/how can we say that any smooth curve $C\in |L|$ has maximal gonality $k=[\frac{g+3}{2}]$ and Clifford dimension 1. Is there some criterion to check if the ample linear system satisfies that? Thanks!

$\textbf{Edit:}$ I am interested in the specific case when $X$ is the Kummer surface associated to an abelian surface $A$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the case when $\mathrm{Pic}(X)=\mathbb{Z}[L]$, as a consequence of two results: the theorem of Lazarsfeld (*Brill-Noether-Petri without degenerations*,
J. Differential Geom. 23 (1986), no. 3, 299-307) which states that a general curve in $|L|$ is Brill-Noether general, hence satisfies your requirement, and the theorem of Green-Lazarsfeld (*Special divisors on curves on a K3 surface*,
Invent. Math. 89 (1987), no. 2, 357-370) which says that all smooth curves in $|L|$ have the same Clifford index.

Comment: Thanks @abx! When $X$ is the Kummer surface associated to an abelian surface, then can this happen? That is the specific case I am looking at. Maybe I should edit the question.

Comment: Unfortunately no -- a Kummer surface has a very high Picard number (>16).

Comment: Doesn't Lazarsfeld actually prove that any smooth curve in $|L|$ is Brill-Noether general (Corollary 1.4 in his paper)?

Comment: @dhy, In the paper, Lazarsfeld assumes that every curve $C\in |L|$ is reduced and irreducible.

Comment: @poorna But that follows from Pic(X)=Z[L]; I think as long as that's true, it doesn't matter if C is generic in the linear system.

Comment: Ah yes, but this does not happen for Kummer surfaces @dhy